# TTF font height calculated by browser is wrong, the importance of baseline

Tags: css, fonts, truetype, typography

I am developing an application where I must have total control over characters occupation in an area. Let's say for example that if my container has a width of 100px, and my letter "A" has a width of 5px, if you insert 20 times "A" i must say "hey your total occupation is 100px".

I created my own TTF font. Characters are displayed in a DIV width 100px, each one wrapped in a SPAN with no given width.

I am using [fontstruct](http://fontstruct.com) to create my own font. After a lot of tests, I got that the "height" of a font is the distance between the upper bound and lower bound. So, for example, if my tallest character is an "A" and it's 6px high, and my lowest character is a "p" and it's 2px under the baseline, so the font height is 8px.

This is relative, of course. I mean that through CSS I can set the font-size to 10px, 11px, whatsoever. **The important thing is that the ratio is correct, so I can get the correct width**. For example: if in my fontstruct editor "A" is 5px wide, than in the browser it will be 5px, if font-size is 8px. It will be 10px wide, if font-size is 16px. And so on.

Having this, if I link my TTF font trough CSS and create a DIV width height:8px and line-height: 8px, than each character displayed on the browser has got the aspected width, for example my "A" is 5px wide in fontstruct's editor, in the browser it is 5px either.

That's fine.
Strange things happen when I draw a character with some pixels under the baseline even if it is a character which commonly does not go lower than the baseline. For example if I draw an "A" 2px under the baseline, when i type some text in the browser (even if i type a B) the width/height is completerly wrong. A si not 5x8, but it is 4x7, for example. Everything is wrong, even for all the rest of the characters. It seems that the browser "knows" which are the characters allowed to go lower than the baseline, messing the things up if i brake this rules.

Ok then, let's assume there is a list of characters which are allowed and not allowed to go lower than the baseline, that i have to follow strictly. I made some research but it seems such a list does not exists! Moreover it seems, to my surprise, that "sometimes" some characters which normally don't go lower the baseline, do go, just to give the illusion they rest correclty over the baseline. For example the rounded one, like G or Q.

According to my tests, anyway, the browser goes mad if I draw any character which "is not supposed to go lower than the baseline" (for example G or Q) under the baseline. So then? Where is the rule? This list? Which set of rules should i follow to create a TTF font to have the total control over its characters' width and height?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you ever will because browsers use different text rendering engines. If you want _full_ control you will have to start drawing it in a different fashion, like with a `canvas` (although, again, text rendering engines... But at least its more controllable). You can use `measureText` to get correct widths, and then draw them at correct offsets manually. But in the browser itself I would never _ever_ rely on fonts being a certain size or them rendering in a very particular way.

Comment: For a TTF font, the defined font size does not depend on where in the character cell the pixels are drawn. If you have a character cell with an EM size of, say, 1024, then that is what your font size depends on; and all the characters are drawn with the same multiplication factor, no matter if your character is a full height pipe or an underscore or whatever. So in your case, something else is going on. Have you applied any hinting?

Comment: Thank you. Both. Ok, I was making a mess with browser cache. Since ttf file was using the same name, it seems that the browser was using "old calculated font size" even if the file was new.
I fixed this, ensuring different ttf file names.